# Check if string ends with special character c#

Tags: c#

Hi I am looking for a solution with checks out if the string ends with a special character, If yes then remove it. The new string after removing special character should also not contain special character.

The special characters should be in array [!@#$%&/{()}=?+] to check against in end of string.

Comment: "after removing special character should also not contain special character" - so, if it *ends* with a special character, that character should be removed *everywhere*, not just from the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)? This method is specifically for removing the characters in a given array from the string.

```
var newstr = s.TrimEnd("[!@#$%&/{()}=?+]".ToCharArray());
```

Also, the following requirement looks like you should be using `String.Replace` to replace any unwanted character in your string:

> The new string after removing special character should also not contain special character

In that case you should do something like this:

```
string unwanted = "[!@#$%&/{()}=?+]";
for (int i = 0; i < unwanted.Length; i++)
    s = s.Replace(unwanted.Substring(i, 1), "");
```

Which removes all occurrances of all unwanted characters from the entire string.

Comment: `TrimEnd` takes `char[]` not `string`, other than that +1.

Comment: You should use `String.ToCharArray()` since this is an instance method of `String` (instead of the generic `Enumerable.ToArray<char>()` extension method)

Comment: Someone edited my answer and added this code - I'll fix it.

Comment: @MartinStettner No `ToArray()` would also work. Just tested it.

Comment: @I4V Yes, of course it would. But it will use the generic approach, calling String's `GetEnumerator` and then iterating the characters one by one through the iterators `Current` property and `MoveNext()` method. This is much slower than String's `ToCharArray()`, which has direct access to the internals of `String`.

Comment: If performance matters, you should not use the second part of this answer imo. This will create a lot of intermediate string objects (calling `Replace` AND `Substring` for every character). I'd rather use regexes for this task.

Comment: +MartinStettner True, but I didn't know ad hoc how to write this using `Regex.Replace` :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] specialArray = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '/', '{', '(', ')', '}', '=', '?', '+'};

for(int i = 0; i < specialArray.length; i++)
{
    if( inputString[inputString.length - 1] == specialArray(i) )
    {
        return inputString.Substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use `TrimEnd` :-)

Comment: Yes but it's nice to solve the problem yourself :)

Comment: ... by reinventing the wheel?

Comment: It's nice to know how to build a wheel even if you don't have to. Especially when your wheel breaks. In any case go for TrimEnd but at least know how and why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (text.LastIndexOfAny("!@#$%&/{()}=?+".ToCharArray()) == (text.Length - 1))
    text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
```

Note that this only trims one character from the end, even if there are multiple characters from the list at the end of the string.

If you want to trim *all* characters in the list from the end of the string, use Thorsten's answer.

So this answer will convert `XXXX!!!` to `XXXX!!`, while Thorsten's will convert `XXXX!!!` to `XXXX`.

Choose the one you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
string x = "ASDF[";
var chars = new char [] { '[','!','@','#','$','%','&','/','{','(',')','}','=','?','+',']' };
string newString = x.TrimEnd(chars);

Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you just want to remove *all* occurences of your special chars (not just at the end)? Seems like a job for `Regex`:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace("[!@#$%&/{()}=?+]", oldString, "");
```

which replaces all characters by an empty string. If performance matters, you could always precompile the `Regex` like

```
var re = new Regex("[!@#$%&/{()}=?+]");
```

and then do

```
var newString = re.Replace(oldString, "");
```

*Note*: I assume, that you didn't mean to erase the characters `'['` and `']'`. If you do, then change the regex to

```
var re = new Regex(@"[!@#$%&/{()}=?+\[\]]");
```

Comment: The OP also wants `[` and `]` to be removed - shouldn't they be quoted in your regular expression?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I wasn't sure, if he really wanted to erase the brackets too or if he only wrote them to limit his "array" of "special chars" ... Made an edit.